# Exercise problem - Returning the longest lign of a txt file

Tags: c

Starting C on my own following Kerningan & Ritchie 2nd edition ANSCI book.

Here, I am supposed to return the longest lign of a text.
very early in the book, so few functions are cited.
My program returns the ligns AFTER the longest lign
A lign being only defined by ending with '.'

I'm probably overstepping on this forum with my beginner level, but i'd appreciate the insight :) thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 1000

void copcol(char cop[], char retour[]);

int main(void)
{

    int nbmax, nbnew, c, i;
    nbmax = nbnew = i = 0 ;
    char lignmax[MAXLEN] ;
    char lignnew[MAXLEN] ;

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        lignnew[i] = c ;
        i++;
        nbnew++ ;
        if( (c == '.') && (nbmax < nbnew) && ( c != '\0'))
        {
            nbmax = nbnew ;
            copcol(lignmax, lignnew);
            nbnew = 0 ;
            i=0 ;
        }
    }
    if ( nbmax > 0 )
        printf("%s",lignmax);
    return 0;
}

void copcol(char new[], char max[])
{
    int i ;
    i=0;
    while((new[i] = max[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

also if a forum is more apropriate for this kind of questions, feel free to let me know.

Comment: You have one major problem: You never null-terminate your strings. I.e. you never write `'\0'` to `lignnew`.

Comment: What is your actual question/problem?

Comment: If you read the file byte by byte anyway then there's no need to place the characters into an array! Lines are separated by either `'\n'` or by `"\r\n"` – if you don't open the file in binary mode, you'll only see the former. In any case, start counting the characters and upon receiving a line terminator you compare with current longest line as usual, remembering current line if new maximum found, increment the line counter and reset the character counter, i.e. restart counting at 0.

Comment: @9769953
- My question is why my program returns the sentences after the longest one, and not the longest one.

Comment: You may want to put that in the question itself. Unless I've overlooked it.

Comment: @Aconcagua i'll work around that :)

Comment: How could `c` ever not be unequal to `\0` if it compared equal to `.` before? That check is obsolete.

Comment: You're not allowed to use library functions like `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` to copy longest string?

Comment: @SparKot not yet no. Glad read the function name thought. Can only use the very basics.

Comment: Oh, need to correct my previous comment: As you need to print out the line's contents, not only the number, then, of course, you need to buffer the contents... Sorry. Still you can just count characters as proposed above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip shorter lines when you encounter period (`.`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 1000

void copcol (char new[], char max[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while ((new[i] = max[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}

int main (void) {
    char lignmax[MAXLEN] ;
    char lignnew[MAXLEN] ;

    int nbmax, nbnew, c;
    nbmax = nbnew = 0 ;

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // nbnew also tracks the new-line-len
        lignnew[nbnew++] = c ;

        if ('.' == c) { // line ended, skip shorter, copy longer line

            if (nbnew > nbmax) { // copying only when longer than current max-line
                nbmax = nbnew ;
                lignnew[nbnew] = '\0'; // terminate string
                copcol (lignmax, lignnew);
            }
            //also ignores shorter-lines
            nbnew = 0 ; // new line begins after the period (.)
        }
    }
    if (nbmax > 0)
        printf ("MaxLength: %d\n MaxLine: [%s]", nbmax, lignmax);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Input period(.) terminated lines cannot be longer than (`MAXLEN -1`), it'll cause buffer-overflow otherwise.

Comment: That's it, thanks. Your answer is explanatory on point, i really appreciate !